# If $x$ is a normal variable with $μ = 5$ and $σ² = 64$, find $(P|x-4|>5)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure whether I am correctly accounting for sigma squared within the equation and whether my math is correct.

$1-p(-5<x-4<5)$

$=1-p(-1<x<9)$

$=1-p((-1-5)/8)<((x-mean)/6)<((9-5)/8)$

$=1-p(-6/8<z<4/8)$

$=1-0.4684835$

$=0.5351649$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Along with this, MathJax formatting is allowed in titles.

Comment: The answer looks alright - http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html use this to verify

Comment: Yes. In R, `1 - diff(pnorm(c(-1,9), 5, 8))` returns $0.5351649.$